# How can I change to DNS of my application in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am very new to Kubernetes world. I have a simple Python API running on a Kubernetes Cluster. The API is now running fine on the host "http://myhost". I would like to change its url so that it can be queried from the url "applicationame.namespacename.myhost" where "applicationname" is the Kubernetes app name and "namespacename" is the name of the namespace.
The application is using 3 manifest files (deployment, service, ingress) which are attached below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: applicationname-deployment
  namespace: namespacename
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: applicationname
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: applicationname
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: applicationname
        image: mydockerimage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080  # Update the container port to 8080
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: applicationname-service
  namespace: namespacename
spec:
  selector:
    app: applicationname
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: applicationname
  namespace: namespacename
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: applicationname-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

I have tried to add the annotation below in the ingress.yml file

`annotations: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`

and changed the host name to `applicationame.namespacename.myhost`. After these changes the API returns an error:
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "applicationname.namespacename.myhost"` 
Anybody could help me? I have the feeling that something very stupid is missing but no idea what.
Thanks!

Comment: It's not quite what you are trying to do. Can you explain what you want and show the curl commands

Comment: What' you're asking takes more than tweaks to the server, you have to change the DNS.  That query happens independently of your service.  You CAN just make an entry in `/etc/hosts` to have a specific name mapped to a specific IP.

Comment: as far as I understand, your question is not really k8s related: you seem to want to have an DNS alias `applicationame.namespacename.myhost` for `myhost` that just happens to be running some k8s node. How to create a DNS alias depends on your network setup, that is not described at all in your question. if it's just your laptop, then as Tim Roberts wrote, an entry in `/etc/hosts` will be sufficient. If you want to run `curl` from other machines on this network, then this network's DNS server must be reconfigured: contact your local admin.